# How to change radial gradient to a square

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients, css-gradients

How do I change the red circle gradient to a square?

That is all I am trying to do in the code.

Is this able to be done?

https://jsfiddle.net/ub1nyfqj/

[image]

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(red 1px, transparent 1px),
    radial-gradient(red 1px, transparent 1px),
    linear-gradient(45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
      transparent 7.5px,
      transparent 10px),
    linear-gradient(-45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
      transparent 7.5px,
      transparent 10px);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
  background-position: 0 0, -5px -5px, 0 0, 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you're looking for but I think [conic-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/conic-gradient()) might be the best solution for you. The only issue is this wouldn't completely line up with your grid but here is what this would look like using this method:

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: conic-gradient(red 90deg, transparent 90deg 270deg),
  linear-gradient(45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
      transparent 7.5px,
      transparent 10px),
    linear-gradient(-45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
      transparent 7.5px,
      transparent 10px);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
  background-position: 0 0, -5px -5px, 0 0, 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

I feel like you can definitely mess around with it more to get it to fit to your grid if this is what you'd like but this should hopefully get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to achieve the effect.

https://jsfiddle.net/7zpr9htf/

[image]

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image:
    conic-gradient(red 9deg, transparent 0 180deg),
    conic-gradient(red 9deg, transparent 0 180deg),
    conic-gradient(red 9deg, transparent 0 180deg),
    conic-gradient(red 9deg, transparent 0 180deg),
    linear-gradient(45deg,

      transparent,
      transparent 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
      transparent 7.5px,
      transparent 10px),
    linear-gradient(-45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
      transparent 7.5px,
      transparent 10px);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
  background-position: 44px -11px, 15px -11px, 20px -6px, 9px -6px, -5px -5px, 0 0, 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Please explanation for the answer